# Create duplicate line based on maximum number of delimiters in a field

Tags: unix, awk, sed, split, delimiter

I have a file which contains multiple fields and 2 types of delimiters.  If the number of delimiters in one of the fields reaches a defined number then I want to split the field after the number is met onto the next line while replicating the first part of the line.

Is this possible in awk or sed?

Example

**Input**

```
a1|b|c|d|1,2,3,4|
a2|b|c|d|1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10|
a3|b|c|d|1,2|
```

Max Number = 6, to split on commas in field 5

**Output**

```
a1|b|c|d|1,2,3,4|
a2|b|c|d|1,2,3,4,5,6|
a2|b|c|d|7,8,9,10|
a3|b|c|d|1,2|
```

Comment: could be there a line like `a3,a4,a5|b|c1,c2,c3,c4|d|1,2,3,4,5|` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming not more than one split would be required:

```
$ sed -E 's/^(([^|]+\|){4})(([^,]+,){5}[^,]+),(.*)/\1\3|\n\1\5/' ip.txt 
a1|b|c|d|1,2,3,4|
a2|b|c|d|1,2,3,4,5,6|
a2|b|c|d|7,8,9,10|
a3|b|c|d|1,2|
```

- `-E` use ERE, some `sed` version uses `-r` option instead
- `^(([^|]+\|){4})` first 4 columns delimited by `|`
- `(([^,]+,){5}[^,]+)` 6 columns delimited by `,` (without trailing `,`)
- `,` comma between 6th and 7th column
- `(.*)` rest of line
- `\1\3|\n\1\5` split as required

The column and max number can be passed from shell variables too (example shown for `bash`)

```
$ col=5; max=6
$ sed -E "s/^(([^|]+\|){$((col-1))})(([^,]+,){$((max-1))}[^,]+),(.*)/\1\3|\n\1\5/" ip.txt 
a1|b|c|d|1,2,3,4|
a2|b|c|d|1,2,3,4,5,6|
a2|b|c|d|7,8,9,10|
a3|b|c|d|1,2|

$ col=5; max=8
$ sed -E "s/^(([^|]+\|){$((col-1))})(([^,]+,){$((max-1))}[^,]+),(.*)/\1\3|\n\1\5/" ip.txt 
a1|b|c|d|1,2,3,4|
a2|b|c|d|1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8|
a2|b|c|d|9,10|
a3|b|c|d|1,2|
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F\| -v OFS=\| -v c=',' '
     {n=split($5,a,c); 
      if(n>6) 
        {f=$5; 
         $5=a[1] c a[2] c a[3] c a[4] c a[5] c a[6]; 
         print; 
         $5=f; 
         gsub(/([^,]+,){6}/,"",$5)}}1' file
```